# Redirect to appropriate pages after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I have installed devise and activeadmin gem. When I try to login via client then I get redirected to the right page but when I try to login via admin I get redirected to the client login page.

#### routes.rb

```
 namespace :admin do
        # get "/stats" => "stats#stats"
        devise_scope :admin_user do
          get '/stats/:scope' => "stats#stats", as: :admin_stats
        end
      end

      devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
      ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
      namespace :client do
        get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: 'dashboard'
      end

      devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
      devise_scope :user do
        root to: 'devise/registrations#new'
      end
```

#### application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    client_dashboard_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
```

How can I fix this?

Here is a link to the test app [enter link description here](http://rsslotto.herokuapp.com)

Admin login [enter link description here](http://rsslotto.herokuapp.com/admin)

Comment: Did you have 2 different model for User and Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  case resource_or_scope
  when AdminUser
    admin_dashboard_path
  when User
    client_dashboard_path
  end
end
```